# aspx page in sandboxed solution

Tags: sandbox-solution

I am working with sharepoint sandbox solution in which I have added visual webpart(sandboxed). My requirement is to add a normal .aspx page to the project and deploy to sharepoint. I have followed the table below.

- Add Module to project and given path of site style library
- rename sample.txt to sample.aspx
- and in source page of aspx page I have written general html code like below

  ```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="sample" %>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
      <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>

      </div>
      </form>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

In the code above sample is the class name. I have added a class file with the name of sample.cs.

I deploy the solution to sharepoint. But accessing the file sample.aspx from the url by navigating to style library will give error.

Can anyone suggest me how can I deploy .aspx pages to sharepoint using sandboxed solution?

Answer (score 1):

You'll not be able to add code behind to an Site Page in a sandboxed solution. So you have to create your page as a web part page with webpartzone(s) and add your code in web parts.

Comment: Thank you :) I have followed the article http://www.akruratechnologies.com/2012/05/14/deploy-custom-aspx-page-with-sandbox-solutions-sharepoint-2010/ This page gets deployed to sharepoint server. But How can i make ajax POST call?

Comment: I have also tried http://www.akruratechnologies.com/2012/05/14/deploy-custom-aspx-page-with-sandbox-solutions-sharepoint-2010/ method..I have deployed a page called MyPage.aspx. and I have added a class file called MyPage.cs. But the ajax POST call is not calling the methods in MyPage.cs ..any idea where have i gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Create a webpart page and embed a webpart into it using elements xml file :

- [Deploy webpart page using module](https://amalhashim.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/sharepoint-deploy-webpart-page-using-module/)
- [Custom application pages in
  the Sandbox Solution](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Custom-application-pages-in-the-SharePoint-2010-Sandbox.aspx)